# Ideal Fermi gas close to $T=0 \rm K$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, fermions, partition-function, chemical-potential

I am reading about the behaviour of ideal Fermi gas close to $T=0K$ from Kardar's Statistical Mechanics.

[image]

In the paragraph which I have highlighted, we have the inyegral representation of $f_m^{-}(z)$.
After that author give some argument and substitute $x=ln(z)+t$.
And the limit changes from $(0,\infty)$ to $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Can someone please explain the logic behind using this substitution? I am not able to understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the substitution and what he talks about is what is more commonly known as the "Sommerfeld expansion". As the temperature $T \rightarrow 0$, one can see that $\beta(\epsilon_{k} - \mu) $ will blow up to $\infty$ unless $\epsilon_{k} < \mu $, where instead it will blow up to $-\infty$. The subsitution $x = Ln(z) + t$ is just the subtitution $\beta\epsilon_{k}  = \beta\mu + t $. So of course in the low temperature limit, as I just explained before, $t$ must extend from $-\infty$ ( in the case of the occupation number being $1$ and $\epsilon_{k} < \mu $ ), and $\infty$ (in the case of the occupation number being $0$ and $\epsilon_{k} > \mu $).